# Prevent direct access to url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, iis, redirect

I know this question has been asked a number of times but I am still lost!

I have a website project (php) that is hosted internally on the Apache server. The site loads with the homepage. The home page contains a `login` link. When the user clicks on `login` a `.htm` page opens in a separate tab that is hosted on another server (outsourced) in IIS. I would like to prevent the users from directly entering the URL of the `login` page in the address bar. Instead the users should always navigate to the `login` page through the project homepage.

The only work around I understood was through the `htaccess` file. This works when the page is on the same server. However, on IIS there is no `htaccess` file.

The other solution was to do a `http post variable` when `login` is clicked. If the variable exist (accessed through homepage) the login page should load otherwise the user should be redirected to the homepage (if the login URL is entered directly). However, I am able to post a variable but I do not understand where to make the call to load the appropriate pages. The following is used to post the variable:

```
<ul>
<li><form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="redirectTest.php">
<input type="hidden" name="total" id="total" value="">
<a href="#" onclick="setValue();">Login</a>
</form></li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function setValue(){
    document.sampleForm.total.value = 100;
    document.forms["loginForm"].submit();
}
</script>
```

The `redirectTest.php` is currently empty as I am not sure how to redirect accordingly.

EDIT:  **For instance, my site is www.abc.com and the login page is at www.xyz.com/login.htm. How can I identify whether this is routed through www.abc.com or the URL directly entered into the address bar?**

Comment: What is "a `.htm` page"?

Comment: The approach with a post variable is not a reliable prevention strategy, if I understood your question correctly. Simply because it can easily be forged. If I see that correctly you want to prevent access to that single "page" delivered by that IIS http server if the request does not carry a referrer header from your other site. If so, then you will have to test for that header on the IIS http server when it is requested to deliver the "login page". If the header is set, fine, if not the prevent access or return a redirection header to that other site.

Comment: @arkascha for compatibility purpose, `html` is also abbreviated as `htm`. Regarding the `test for that header on the IIS http server when it is requested to deliver the "login page"`, can you please explain where this `header` is located and what kind of validation test to put in place?

Comment: It is a normal http header browsers add to a request when following a link instead of loading a url directly entered. It is documented. It contains the url of the page holding the link, so "the page the user comes from". It is available as part of the request on server side, PHP provides it inside its `$_SERVER` superglobal variable as element `HTTP_REFERRER`, which is also documented. It can also be evaluated by the http server itself, though I cannot help you with that. Like probably 99% of all uses here I have very limited experience with IIS, it is simply a rare and exotic http server.

Answer (score 0):

On the login page, you can use the variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. This will contain the name of the page where you clicked the link on. You can then use it in an if statement like so:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://domain.com/page_with_login_link.php")
```

In javascript, the http referer can be accessed through `document.referer`

Comment: The `login` page is in htm, I cannot use a `php` tag in there.

Comment: @Sarah You could try doing it with javascript, see my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, this is clear now. However my question - when the `login` is clicked from `my` site, the `login` page that loads is not prefixed through `my` site. For instance, my site is `www.abc.com` and the login page is at `www.xyz.com/login.htm`. How will the above `js` identify whether this is routed through `www.abc.com` or the URL directly entered into the address bar?